# Switch between two terminals with ALT-TAB (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, window-manager, application-switcher

I have to switch between two terminals very often.

One terminal is a ssh-session to a local test-server and the other terminal is a ssh-session to a remote production server.

I am used to switching between windows with <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Is there a way to make Ubuntu 18.04 switch between both with <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>?

Comment: You mean `alt + \`` ?

Comment: What does `alt +`` do? On my keyboard it does nothing.

Comment: Switching between windows of an application. It should be above the Tab. What's your keyboard?